# how to map an mvc action parameter with a value of null correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm posting a serialized string to an MVC action in C# where an empty parameter (i.e. &test=&another=10) maps to a value of 0.0.  Any suggestions please?  I need the value to  evaluate to null as opposed to 0.0.  Code segments below.
Many thanks!

**Update:** The value can be 10, 100.00, 0.0 or null.

**Ajax Post**

```
$.ajax({
   type: method,
   url: url,
   data: data,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: settings.success,
   error: settings.error,
   async: !options.sync
});
```

**MVC Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[NoCache]
[JsonContractExceptionFilter]
public ActionResult Save(ViewModel data)
{
    data.Test == 0.0  // should be null
```

**Property inside the model class**

```
public double? Test
{
   get { return obj.test; }
   set { obj.test = value; }
}
```

**Update 2 - Contents of obj**

```
public virtual Nullable<double> Test
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

**Update 3**

```
public ActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))] ViewModel data)
{
   ...
}
```

**The custom binder**

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{  
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
       var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

       // Default binder
       var temp = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

       // TODO - Find my property and change the value?

       return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `data` is of type `ViewModel` not `Query`, show the relevant code, please.

Comment: try with string property then convert it to double using `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: Is obj.test nullable double?

Comment: @Vasanth its a double? (see the bottom code snippet)

Comment: What is obj under the hood? Any reason not to use auto properties?

Comment: have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two good options for you here.  You can try to use a custom model binder (more difficult) or you can just check the querystring from the Request object (easier).

[Custom Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)

...or to access the name-value collection use the following:

```
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
```

[ParseQueryString method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

A sample implementation of a model binder that could help you would be something like this (based on your updated question):

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // Default binder
        var temp = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var nulledValue = request.QueryString["test"];
        if (nulledValue == "0.0")
        {
            // cast your temp to MyInvoice and set the property here...
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks but how can I override the model binder easily which uses the default binder and then for my property that has the problem to simply modify that value?

Comment: added a sample, hope it helps!